# PlaceLikelihoodBuffer is null

Tags: android, google-maps, github

I am working on Google Maps and trying to run a github project: "Select Current Place and Show Details on a Map" [this is the link](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/tutorials/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap) . But when i am running the project then it throws a Null Pointer exception on "PlaceLikelihoodBuffer". The block of code where null is returning is this

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                int i = 0;
                if (!likelyPlaces.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    // Request did not complete successfully
                    Toast.makeText(MapsMarkerActivity.this, "Request did not complete successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    likelyPlaces.release();
                    return;
                }
                mLikelyPlaceNames = new String[mMaxEntries];
                mLikelyPlaceAddresses = new String[mMaxEntries];
                mLikelyPlaceAttributions = new String[mMaxEntries];
                mLikelyPlaceLatLngs = new LatLng[mMaxEntries];
                Log.e("result",likelyPlaces.toString());
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    // Build a list of likely places to show the user. Max 5.
                    mLikelyPlaceNames[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName();
                    mLikelyPlaceAddresses[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress();
                    mLikelyPlaceAttributions[i] = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                            .getAttributions();
                    mLikelyPlaceLatLngs[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng();

                    i++;
                    if (i > (mMaxEntries - 1)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Release the place likelihood buffer, to avoid memory leaks.
                likelyPlaces.release();

                // Show a dialog offering the user the list of likely places, and add a
                // marker at the selected place.
                openPlacesDialog();
            }
        });
```

Actually in above code likelyPlaces is null. I want to ask that why likelyPlaces are null and how to solve this error.

**UPDATE**

These are the Log details

> E/result: PlaceLikelihoodBuffer{status=Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}, attributions=null}

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
```

> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
>                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

[image: This is the screenshot]

When we click on Get Places button then this error appears.

Answer (score 0):

you are right about the problem being in "placeLikelihood", I ran into the same problem and after some research found out that I forgot to enable "Google Places API for Android" from Google Developer Console. This should solve the null pointer exception.
Go to this link: https://console.developers.google.com .Then choose your connected app and click on enable API. Then on the next page search for the Google Places API and enable it, the above problem would be resolved. Cheers!